# Bounding $L_p$ norms on a convergent $L_1$ sequence

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, lebesgue-integral, banach-spaces, lp-spaces

I've encountered a prelim problem on $L_p$ spaces that I'm pretty stuck on.  Suppose $1 < p < \infty$ and $f_n \in L_1([0,1]) \cap L_p([0,1])$, with $||f_n||_p$ bounded above by some constant $M$.

To show: If $f \in L_1([0,1])$ is such that $||f_n - f||_1 \rightarrow 0$, then $||f||_p < \infty$.

I haven't managed to start this off.  Note that $f_n$ might not converge to $f$ in $L_p$, e.g. take $\sqrt{n} \cdot \chi_{[0, \frac{1}{n}]}$.  Can somebody give me the first step or two?  I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: Fatou?${}{}{}{}$

Comment: I also think it's Fatou since none of the usual tricks seem relevant, but if you have a proof structure in mind could you elaborate?

Comment: A subsequence of $(f_n)$ converges a.e to $f$. Apply Fatou to $(|f|^p)$.

Comment: Ahhhhh, it works, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to choose a subsequence $\left(f_{n_j}\right)_{j\geqslant 1}$ which converges to $0$ almost everywhere. Applying Fatou's lemma to the non-negative sequence $\left(\left\lvert   f_{n_j}\right\rvert^p  \right)_{j\geqslant 1}$, we get 
$$\int \left\lvert   f\right\rvert^p=\int\liminf_{j\to +\infty}      \left\lvert   f_{n_j}\right\rvert^p \leqslant \liminf_{j\to +\infty}\int      \left\lvert   f_{n_j}\right\rvert^p \leqslant\sup_{i}\left\lVert f_i\right\rVert^p_p     < +\infty.$$